# R blastula's send_stmp gives "MAIL failed: 451"

Tags: r, smtp, blastula

I'm trying to send emails through R's blastula package. My email program is Outlook/Office. This code

```
library(blastula)

smtp_send(
  compose_email(body = "hello"),
  to = "hello@hello.com", 
  from = "hello@hello.com",
  credentials = creds(
    user = "hello",
    host = "smtp.office365.com",
    port = 587,
    use_ssl = F
  ))
```

gives

```
Error in curl_fetch_memory(smtp_server, handle = h) : MAIL failed: 451
```

I've done a bit of reading and it clearly has something to do with permissions being blocked, which I assume I can't change because I don't have admin privileges on my machine.

Is there anything I can do?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: Nope =(

I gave up and wrote a script in Python that does something similar to what I wanted. I'd still prefer to use Blastula but what can you do?